# PCA plot by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-point

I have plotted a PCA plot in R using ggplot2's geom_point function.

I would like to have a black color border around the points.

This is the code and picture before i gave color argument to geom_point

[image]

[image]

So here i want to introduce border around the dots for which i used color argument and following are the picture

[image]

[image]

as you can see the dots turned to black color. how to fix this and get the black border around the dots.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with `color` and `shape` of `geom_point()`.

Originally, `color` of `geom_point()` in `ggplot2` is the border color of points. That's why the result of your second code line rendered.

However, when designating a specific `shape` with `fill`, you can render color-filled points with black `border`.

Here's an example with `iris` data.

```r
library(ggplot2)
iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=Species), color="black",shape=21, size=7,
             stroke =1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Additionally, you can check the symbols of points here.

```r
ggpubr::show_point_shapes()
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You want to map your *condition* variable to the fill aesthetic for your points, and let the color be black. For this to work you will also need to choose a different shape for your points, such as `shape = 21`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, color = 'black')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `geom_point` layers in the plot and also the shape should be set on `shape=1` or `shape=21` etc. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  x=rnorm(10),
  y=rnorm(10),
  id=sample(c('red','green','blue'),10,replace = T)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=id), size=12, show.legend = F) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 12, colour = "black")
```

and the output is:
[image]